# stdClass vs array. Which is recommended?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, stdclass

Where is recommended to use one of them? I want to store data from articles listed from db.

It's a simple question:

```
echo $Datastore->name; //I like it works with foreach

//vs

echo $Datastore['name'];
```

Which is the best? Is there any difference between `stdClass` and `array` speed of getting elements?

Comment: Closing as opinion-based, but personally I prefer arrays because there's a bunch of useful array functions that you just can't use on stdClasses.

Comment: Downvoting. Useless question, you can't ask which is *best*. You should think "what approach am I supposed to use to make life easier for myself and my colleagues". Speed wise - it's irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is better stdClass or (object) array to store related data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640607/what-is-better-stdclass-or-object-array-to-store-related-data)

Comment: @KA_lin what on earth are you talking about? Using an array or an object is not procedural v OOP. Please dont confuse people about things like that.

Comment: @PhilSturgeon: I didn`t formulated correctly sorry b`out that :)

Comment: Strongly disagree about closing the question. Maybe it's a bit too broad, but I'm reading it as 'what are pros&cons of using assoc array over stdClass?' And I'm sorry for people who close the question because they don't feel like or are not able to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: There's a foggy area where opinions cross over to a debate about advantages and disadvantages. Both of them are critical for understanding the contents as it brings forward various important contributing factors. I strongly disagree with Stackoverflow's policy of closing opinionated questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a similar question **What is better stdClass or (object) array to store related data?** with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18640919/619616)

> Based on small test (http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/cz0-hyf) I can say
>   that using "new stdClass()" is about 3 times slowlier than other
>   options.
>
> It is strange, but casting an array is done very efficiently compared
>   to stdClass.
>
> But this test meters only execution time. It does not meter memory.
>
> P.S. I used phpFiddle only to share code. Test were done at my local
>   PC.

[In answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23999743/619616) you can see this conclusion:

> 1. For arrays, PHP 5.5 is faster than PHP 5.4, for object it is pretty much the same
> 2. Class is slower than Arrays thanks to the optimization of PHP 5.5 and arrays.
> 3. stdClass is evil.
> 4. Class still uses less memory than Arrays. (about 30-40% less!!).
> 5. SplFixedArray is similar to use a Class but it uses more memory.

Comment: You can pass true as a 2nd argument to json_decode to get the results back as arrays rather than stdClass.

In my scenario I was writing out JSON to a file, then parsing it back on next execution, but array functions were not working on stdClass go figure...